# Removing unnecessary elements from an image

Tags: opencv

I have successfully extracted a speed sign from an image using OpenCV, the output is something like this

[image]

Now I need to recognize the numbers. For it to work properly I have to remove the ellipse around the numbers and that's what I have trouble with.

I've tried finding countours and fitting an ellipse so I could extract the inside and I've tried to remove background noise through dilatation and erosion but this ruins the numbers so that tesseract is unable to identify them.

Any ideas how to remove these ellipses?

If it helps I know the `RotatedRect` of this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

1º Find contours -> Obtain your biggest circle

2º Generate a circle mask from it

3º Find, by experimentation, how much do you need to resize it to be able to have your numbers inside it.

4º Move this new mask to the center of the biggest circle (center it).

5º Apply the mask

Since your image is "symmetric", you shouldn't have problems with that. Of course, there may be more efficient ways to do it, but I just thought this one.

Good luck

Comment: Currently it does not find correct contours. This may be because the images are quite small, mainly below 50x50px. Maybe I should try resizing the image before finding contours. I'll post some results when I get them :)

Comment: You can try by applying a `dilate` operation first, then getting contours (external one, that is your objective), and then drawing it as a `convexhull`. With this you should have your circle @user3960875

Comment: the problem is that it does not find any contours on that image.

`Imgproc.findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` returns a black image.

Comment: Show your code in order to find the problem @user3960875. It's quite weird what you're saying. By the way, how are you using `RETR_EXTERNAL` and `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` from a Mat, that's not possible. Use `cv::` (`cv::RETR_EXTERNAL`) instead.

Comment: Got it working now. I just calculated min rectangle that fits in the smaller ellipse and extracted it thus leaving only numbers. Thanks for help!

Comment: For future visitors Btc Sources answer also works. I just had to reduce dilatation iterations.

Use something like this
`Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE,new Size(3,3));
                Imgproc.dilate(numbers,numbers,kernel,new Point(-1,-1),5);`